# Como puedo ponerle nombre a los parámetros en este json?

Tags: json, babel, babeljs

Al mandar una petición a un WS, tengo el siguiente json de retorno.

```
[
    0,
    "Exito",
    [
        {
            "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
            "nro_cuota": "3",
            "saldo": "149000.00",
            "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-06-04"
        },
        {
            "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
            "nro_cuota": "4",
            "saldo": "149000.00",
            "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-07-04"
        },
        {
            "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
            "nro_cuota": "5",
            "saldo": "149000.00",
            "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-08-04"
        }
    ]
]
```

Y como se puede apreciar hay campos que son directamente valores como el **0** y **Éxito**. Hay forma de mi parte de darle parámetros a esos resultados? o desde mi parte eso ya es difícil?.

> Como dato adicional, estoy recibiendo eso por babel.

La idea seria que quede de esta manera:

```
[
    "codigo": 0,
    "mensaje": "Éxito",
    "detalleRespuesta":[
        {
            "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
            "nro_cuota": "3",
            "saldo": "149000.00",
            "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-06-04"
        },
        {
            "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
            "nro_cuota": "4",
            "saldo": "149000.00",
            "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-07-04"
        },
        {
            "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
            "nro_cuota": "5",
            "saldo": "149000.00",
            "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-08-04"
        }
    ]
]
```

Aguardo cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias

Comment: Deberías añadir qué has intentado, pero como era algo muy simple te preparé un respuesta.

Comment: Pero la respuesta es un arreglo, y lo que tu propones no es un JSON válido. Lo que tu quieres tener es equivalente a: `[ "key": "value" ]` <- y eso no es un JSON válido. Debería ser: `[{ "key": "value" }]`. Te recomiendo que leas sobre JSON. https://www.json.org/json-es.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aplica `destructuring` para obtener los datos del Array y formatea el nuevo JSON con los datos extraídos.

```js
const originalData = [
    0,
    "Exito",
    [
        {
            "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
            "nro_cuota": "3",
            "saldo": "149000.00",
            "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-06-04"
        },
        {
            "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
            "nro_cuota": "4",
            "saldo": "149000.00",
            "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-07-04"
        },
        {
            "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
            "nro_cuota": "5",
            "saldo": "149000.00",
            "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-08-04"
        }
    ]
];


const [codigo, mensaje, detalleRespuesta] = originalData;

const data = { codigo, mensaje, detalleRespuesta };

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jose Hermosilla Rodrigo, esa era la forma y me funciono, sabes que quise aplicar en un trabajo que estoy y no me permitieron XD, pero bueno de igual forma te agradezco y a los demás también.

Comment: Hola @VictorAvila, Cuál fue el motivo? Si el motivo es que la sintaxis es demasiado "moderna", pese a que está soportada por la gran mayoría de los navegadores y entornos actuales, hay alternativas.